# pdf.save is not a function error in jspdf using in Angular 6

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am Using Latest Version of jsPDF in angular 6

Package :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

***Source Code***

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

 public captureScreen() 
    {
        var data = document.getElementById('print');
        html2canvas(data).then(canvas => 
            {
            // Few necessary setting options
            var imgWidth = 208;
            var pageHeight = 295;
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            var heightLeft = imgHeight;

            const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
            var position = 0;
            pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
            pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF 

        });
    }
```

***Error***

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: pdf.save is not a function
TypeError: pdf.save is not a function
at app.generateRecepit.Component.ts:59
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:14060)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at zone.js:872
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
at zone.js:877
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.5.3 got released and fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Download dist new folder from below link

[Link to download dist folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DS3wh3MkW7YtBWBQDkAPgT0RUOoQgr75)

Step 2:- Check jspdf folder in node_modules

[image]

Step 3:- Extract the downloaded dist.zip file and replace with files present in the node_modules jspdf folder.

**Final step** Import jsPDF in this way.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

Link for more details:- [view details](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2176)

Answer (score 0):

use version 1.4.2, its stable & not having that Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jspdf current version to Version 1.5.3 new update fixes these issues